# Binomial Probability Word Problem

Tags: probability, statistics

This problem appears very simple, but I am almost positive that it should not be so simple. For the question below I reason that the probability for part *a* is 0.6 and part *b* is 0.6 as well. What am I missing?

> Q:Hirsbrunner produces tubas and ships them in lots of twenty. 
>   Suppose that 60% of all such lots contain no defective tubas, 30% 
>   contain one defective, and 10% contain two defectives.  Now suppose 
>   that a lot is inspected, with two tubas being selected from it at 
>   random, and neither is found to be defective.
>
> a) What is the probability that there are no defectives in that lot?
>
> b) Suppose that the inspected lot is from a shipping container that 
>   contains 10 lots, and the other 9 lots were not inspected.  What is 
>   the probability that there are no defectives in that container?

Comment: You need to find the probability that two randomly selected tubas are both nondefective. This will require use of the _law of total probability._ Then, you will need to use _Bayes' formula_ to determine the _conditional_ probability that the lot is one of the $60\%$ _nondefective_ lots _given_ that both selected tubas are fine.  This is _usually_ not the same as the probability of neither selected tuba being defective _given_ that the lot is one of the $60\%$ lots with no defective tubas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) Let $G$ be the event that the whole lot is good (zero defectives), and let $P$ be the event there were no defectives in the sample of $2$. We are asked for the conditional probability $\Pr(G|P)$, the probability that the whole lot is good **given** the information that the sample of $2$ had no defectives. By a formula which is likely familiar to you, essentially the *definition* of conditional probability, we have
$$\Pr(G|P)=\frac{\Pr(G\cap P}{\Pr(P)}.$$
It remains to find the probabilities on the right.

We go first for the harder one, $\Pr(P)$. The event $P$ can happen in three ways: (i) the chosen lot has no defectives, and (of course) no defectives are found; (ii) the chosen lot has one defective, and no defectives are found; or (iii) the chosen lot has two defectives, and no defectives are found.

The probability of (i) is clearly $0.6$. Note that this is also $\Pr(P\cap G)$.

The probability that the chosen lot has $1$ defective is $0.3$. If we sample from this lot, then with probability $\frac{19}{20}$ the first tested item is OK, and given that happened, the probability the second item tested is OK is $\frac{18}{19}$, for a product of $\frac{18}{20}$. So the probability of (ii) is $(0.3)(18/20)$, which is exactly $0.27$.

In the same way, we find that the probability of (iii) is $(0.1)(18/20)(17/19)$, which is approximately $0.0805$.

So $\Pr(P)\approx 0.6+0.27+0.0805$, which is about $0.9505$.

Finally, for our conditional probability, divide $\Pr(G\cap P)$ by $\Pr(P)$. We get about $0.63123$.

(b) We are expected to assume independence. For the inspected lot, the probability it has no defectives is approximately $0.63213$. The $9$ uninspected lots each have probability $0.6$ of having no defectives. Multiply.

**Remark:** Our $0.63123$ is *a little* bigger than your conjectured answer of $0.6$. This is because the fact that no bads were found in our inadequate inspection makes it somewhat more likely that the lot is an all-good lot.

Answer (score 0):

For a, you are missing that not finding a defective improves the odds that there is none.  The chance of finding no defectives is $60\% (\text{no defectives}) + 30\%\cdot \frac {19\choose 2}{20\choose 2}(\text{one defective and missed it}) \\ +10\%\cdot \frac {18\choose 2}{20\choose 2}(\text{two defective and missed them})\approx 60\%+27\%+8.05\%=95.05\%$  The chance that there are no defectives given the inspection is then $\frac {60}{95.05}\approx 63.12\%$

For b, if you don't inspect any others, the chance that the other nine lots have no defectives is $0.6^9$ and you need  to multiply the answer from a by this.

Answer (score 0):

For (a), imagine that you have ten lots, six with no defectives, three with one defective each, and one with two defectives. In other words, imagine that you’re facing a concrete situation in which the probabilities work out exactly. This is always legitimate in such problems.

If you pick one of the first six to test, there are $\binom{20}2$ ways to pick two tubas to test, and in every case both will be good. If you pick one of the next three lots to test, only $\binom{19}2$ of the $\binom{20}2$ possible samples will contain no defective. And if you choose the last lot, only $\binom{18}2$ of the $\binom{20}2$ possible samples will contain no defective.

Since you actually found no defective tuba in the sample, it must have been one of the $$6\binom{20}2+3\binom{19}2+\binom{18}2$$ possible samples containing no defective tuba. $6\binom{20}2$ of those samples came from lots with no defective tuba, so the probability that the sample came from such a lot is

$$6\frac{\binom{20}2}{6\binom{20}2+3\binom{19}2+\binom{18}2}=\frac{1140}{1806}\approx 0.63123\;.$$

The textbook solution of such problems uses [Bayes’ theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem). If $A_0,A_1$, and $A_2$ are the events that the lot contains $0,1$, or $2$ defectives respectively, and $B$ is the event that we find no defective tubas, then Bayes’ theorem says that

$$\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Pr}(A_0|B)&=\frac{\mathrm{Pr}(B|A_0)\mathrm{Pr}(A_0)}{\mathrm{Pr}(B|A_0)\mathrm{Pr}(A_0)+\mathrm{Pr}(B|A_1)\mathrm{Pr}(A_1)+\mathrm{Pr}(B|A_2)\mathrm{Pr}(A_2)}\\\\
&=\frac{1\cdot0.6}{1\cdot0.6+\frac{\binom{19}2}{\binom{20}2}\cdot0.3+\frac{\binom{18}2}{\binom{20}2}\cdot0.1}\\\\
&=\frac{0.6}{0.6+\frac{19\cdot18}{20\cdot19}\cdot0.3+\frac{18\cdot17}{20\cdot19}\cdot0.1}\\\\
&\approx0.63123\;.
\end{align*}$$

In (b), the answer to (a) gives the probability that the inspected lot contains no defectives. Each of the other nine lots independently has probability $0.6$ of having no defectives, so the probability that all nine have no defectives is only $0.6^9$. To get the probability that there are no defective tubas in the entire container. you have to multiply this figure by the answer to (a); the result is only about $0.00636$, so this inspection proceduce isn’t very effective!